# Most efficient way to retrieve a unique list of keys from all rows of an hstore?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, hstore

For simplicity sake, say I have a table with a single column that is just an hstore. What is the most efficient way to go about getting a unqiue list of all the keys from all rows of the hstore?

eg.

```
my_hstore
------------
a=>1,b=>2
b=>2,c=>3
x=>10,y=>11
y=>11,z=12
```

What is the most efficient way to retrieve a list/array/set containing (a,b,c,x,y,z) ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's always the straight forward [`skeys`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) approach:

```
select distinct k
from (
    select skeys(my_hstore) as k
    from your_table
) as dt
```

And if you need an array, then add an [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

```
select array_agg(distinct k)
from (
    select skeys(my_hstore) as k
    from your_table
) as dt
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. It certainly is quick, but is it the most efficient without going way overboard and getting excessively complex? Are there any sort of indexes I could add that would speed up such queries?

Comment: Looking at the docs, I didn't see reference to the fact that the keys of an hstore would be indexed (and it makes sense since an hstore is supposed to be a generic container, not to have the same features as a indexed table). So I guess the above query is the most efficient.

Comment: An hstore column can be indexed with GiST (and maybe GIN, I'm not sure), but I don't see any way that such an index could be useful for *this* particular query. Searching for specific key/value pairs *is* going to be faster with an index if you have very many rows in the table. In general, indexing doesn't help on tables in which all the data fits in one or two pages.

Comment: @kgrittn: Any ideas on how do this in a way that wouldn't be a table scan? I suppose you could have a `(key,n)` cache table and some triggers to maintain the counters (`n`) and delete cache table rows when `n = 0` but that might be too much machinery.

Comment: @muistooshort: I'm drawing a blank on any alternatives to avoid a table scan which are simpler than such triggers.

Comment: I think `select distinct skeys(my_hstore) from my_table` works

Comment: @hasen Yes, that works (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ede4f/3) but I'm not sure how you'd get an array without the derived table (assuming they wanted an array). Might be worth converting that comment into an answer.

Comment: @muistooshort sorry for the confusion, my comment was not in response to your question. Just a general comment about the answer since it seemed a bit verbose.

Comment: @hasen But the `select distinct k` approach is overly verbose so no harm done.